# Argh! Passbook - tables are not updating

Tags: php, mysql, passbook

**Apple pass for passbook :**

I have implemented the pass itself, and want to communicate for updates etc.
For server side (webserviceUrl) I am using the code below that I have adjusted. I am not very experienced in php, so any help would be great!

On console when installing a pass, it matches the authorization code, seems to be working, but the code below is not updating my tables.

Tables :

**Devices** {DeviceID, push_token} empty -

**Registration** {device_id, pass_id, pass_type} empty

Also have a table **Passes** which consists of serial, PassID, authtoken, and other information about the pass - complete

```
 <?php

      $servername = "hostname";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1));



    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "POST"

        && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])

        && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 'ApplePass') === 0

        && $request[2] === "devices"

        && $request[4] === "registrations") {



        $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);



        $device_id = $request[3];

        $pass_id = $request[5];

        $serial = $request[6];



        // Catch the JSON post and decode it

        $dt = @file_get_contents('php://input');

        $device_token = json_decode($dt);

        $device_token = $device_token->pushToken;





        $sql="INSERT INTO Registrations (device_id, pass_id, pass_type) VALUES ('".$device_id."', '".$pass_id."', '".$serial."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "y";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;


      $sql="INSERT INTO Devices (DeviceID, push_token) VALUES ( '".$device_id."', '".$device_token."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "y";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
     mysql_query($sql,$link);

    exit;

        }

    }}
    ?>
```

Any input would be really helpful at this point.

Comment: Starting to think this is to do with the redirect type -as in it redirects using apache but does not keep the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out for anyone who comes across this. My redirect to the webserviceurl was incorrect. Here is what I put into .htaccess - this meant my code was essentially not dicing up the url information.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```